# Programmatically disconnect the call through iOS app

Tags: ios

I have requirement to make a call from my iOS app and disconnect it after a particular time period say 20 secs.

I was able to make the call successfully using tel://, how to achieve call disconnection through code?

Comment: This can only be done for non-App Store apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disconnect the OS call programmatically.

No public API is provided by Apple for doing so.

Comment: Thanks. is there any private framework to achieve this?

Comment: the private frameworks/headers can be seen here https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks i am not sure if any of them has the method of disconnecting , but you should check the one related to Telephony or Call related. good luck

Comment: Thanks :) Any idea if this can be achieved through socket programming ? I am new to socket programming

Comment: it cannot be done with sockets. Sockets are related to networking and not to calls. Please mark the answer correct if it is a proper solution to your question